# Is this the correct use of the $\lor$ symbol?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I have little to no knowledge about logical operators, so please pardon me if the answer to this question is obvious.

Let's say that we have a simple statement related to set theory. It states that if $x \in U$, where $U$ denotes the universal set and we're talking about a system of two sets only, specifically, $A$ and $B$, then either $x \in A \cap B$ or $x \in A-B$ or $x \in B-A$ or $x \in (A \cup B)^c$, then can this s help write like this :
$$x \in U \implies x \in A-B ~\lor x \in B-A ~\lor x \in A \cap B ~\lor x \in (A \cup B) ^c$$

Thanks!

Comment: Your English sentence is true and the logical statement is true, but the logical statement is not a faithful translation of the English sentence because either... or is not the same as the logical "or" symbol. "Either $A$ or $B$" implies that $A$ and $B$ cannot both be true. $A \lor B$ is true even when both $A$ and $B$ are true.

Comment: @daviddiaz So, is there some other specific symbol for this? Maybe, $\wedge$?

Comment: $\land$ means AND. "Either $a$ or $b$" is the XOR (exclusive OR) operation: $a \oplus b = (\neg a \land b) \lor (a \land \neg b)$.

Comment: Your statement is correct.

Comment: @alexandru Thanks!